# How to align group content without centering everything within it?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to centre some content boxes in the middle of my website, however whenever I try to centre them with something like the following, it doesn't seem to centre properly. So does anyone know how I can centre these content boxes properly and point me in the right direction? Thanks.

> 'top: 50%;, bottom: 50%; ,transform: translate(-50%, -50%);'

```css
body {
      background-color: #323232;
      max-width: 960px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Lato;
      }

      nav a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px 25px;
      display: inline-block;
      }

      .fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #202020;
      }

      .fixed-header {
      top: 0;
      }

      .fixed-footer {
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 20px 0px;
      }

      .fixed-header a:hover {
      color: #c1c1c1;
      }

      .fixed-footer a {
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: lighter;
      text-decoration: none;
      }

      .group-content {
      max-width: 960px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-evenly;

      }

      .group-content h3 {
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: white;
      }

      .group-content p {
      margin-top: 3px;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: white;
      }

      .content {
      width: 30%;
      background-color: #202020;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .content >* {
      max-width: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

     <head>
      <title>Kumo99.cf</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
     </head>

     <body>

    <div class="fixed-header">
       <nav>
         <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
         <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
         <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
       </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="fixed-footer">
     <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/kumo99">Made by Kumo © 2018</a>
    </div>

    <div class="group-content">
       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Arma 3: Exile Server</h3>
         <p>A project for improving the exile mod.</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>
     </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to set the div's width to a specific value i.e. 75%, and the margin to be "0 auto" which auto centers it horizontally. In your case you would also need to make your body width 100% because that is the element the div is centering itself in. If you don't want your body to be 100% you can make it whatever width you want and apply the "0 auto" margin to your body as well so it is centered on the page. However by doing that you will have to play around with your other elements to get them back to where they are now. 
Try replacing your corresponding css with the css below...

```
body {
  background-color: #323232;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Lato;
}

.group-content {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 75px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Notice how the margin in .group-content is set to "75px auto". This accounts for the navbar and footer to make sure the .group-content is all able to be seen by adding a 75px top and bottom margin.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the solution worked fine, however, I changed the width to 100% for it to center correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body {
  background-color: #323232;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Lato;
 }
      nav a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 20px 25px;
      display: inline-block;
      }

      .fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: #202020;
      }

      .fixed-header {
      top: 0;
      }

      .fixed-footer {
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 20px 0px;
      }

      .fixed-header a:hover {
      color: #c1c1c1;
      }

      .fixed-footer a {
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: lighter;
      text-decoration: none;
      }


 

  .group-content {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 75px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

      .group-content h3 {
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: white;
      }

      .group-content p {
      margin-top: 3px;
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: white;
      }

      .content {
      width: 30%;
      background-color: #202020;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .content >* {
      max-width: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

     <head>
      <title>Kumo99.cf</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
     </head>

     <body>

    <div class="fixed-header">
       <nav>
         <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
         <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
         <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
       </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="fixed-footer">
     <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/kumo99">Made by Kumo © 2018</a>
    </div>

    <div class="group-content">
       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Arma 3: Exile Server</h3>
         <p>A project for improving the exile mod.</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>

       <div class="content">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KPHMNie.png">
         <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
         <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
       </div>
     </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This centres is slightly, but it's still not perfect. You can see here, there is a larger gap on the bottom half. http://prntscr.com/hto43r

Answer (score 0):

1. You have fixed body width to 960px make your width to 100%
2. make group content margin to margin:auto;

CSS:

```
  body {
      background-color: #323232;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Lato;
    }
    .group-content {
      max-width: 960px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
```

Working JSFiddle: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/1uosfu4g/)